# Different size when scanning depending on the method (USB, WiFi direct to Mac and PC)

Tags: pdf, jpeg, scanner, tiff

I scanned a paper today using three different methods:

1. USB inserted into the scanner (an [HP Color LaserJet MFP M477fdw](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-color-laserjet-pro-mfp-m477-series/7326560/model/7326586))
2. WiFi direct to Image Capture on a Mac
3. WiFi direct to [Scan](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-scan/9wzdncrfj3pv?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) on Windows 10

The resulting file size for the three different methods were 330 kB, 565 kB and 1.7 MB (!). All where using the same settings (colour, 300 dpi).

A screen shot of the three files zoomed in 1000 % (weirdly enough, when I zoomed the file that originated on Windows, the zoom level to achieve the same zoom as the other scans was 250 %. I'm 100 % confident I didn't scan that file in 1200 dpi (the scanner only supports 600 dpi)):

[Mac to the left, USB in the middle and Windows to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDIhn.jpg)

Even at this zoom level it is hard to say that any of them are significantly better. There are some differences but it is hard to say that one is better than the other.

So why is the Windows scan ≈ 4 times bigger than the other two? I think I have read somewhere that PDF supports two internal image formats, JPG and TIFF. Can it be that the Mac and the printer uses JPG while Windows uses TIFF?

Unfortunately, I am mostly gonna use Windows with this scanner, are there any options to Microsofts Scan app I can use that generates smaller files?

Comment: Judging from the artifacts in the images you posted (thanks for that, by the way), they're all probably JPGs.  If so, though, they're definitely saved at different quality levels. Check to see if the Windows app gives you a setting for quality or compression. It'd be worth trying a serious scanning app like VueScan (https://www.hamrick.com/) instead of the Windows Scan app.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to get the proper answer in this situation is to contact HP support.  If anyone is aware of how and why this issue is happening, it will be HP.

Having said that, I *think* the issue comes down to the PDF writing software that is being used.  I doubt HP created their own software to write PDF, but instead licensed someone else's software.  The PDF writer HP uses in their software for Windows, is different than the PDF writer Microsoft uses in the OS, which is also different from that on the Mac.  You can see this by taking a simple text file and write a PDF from different programs and see the resulting file sizes will be different. Some programs just write smaller, more efficient PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

There are JPG images, and then there are compressed [JPG images](https://www.jotform.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-image-compression/). [JPEG compression](http://learnmem.cshlp.org/site/misc/tsg_JPEG_instructions.pdf) is popular in apps; sometimes you don't have access to how much compression, and [which compression methods](https://bytescout.com/blog/2014/06/pros-and-cons-of-jpeg-image-compression.html), are used, and you can't obtain the [amount or method of compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024947/is-it-possible-to-tell-the-quality-level-of-a-jpeg) by [looking in the metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336004/detect-jpg-compression-rate) of a JPG file.